# VBA Hide Row in table if Specified Column is Empty

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add to a macro I have that will hide every row that has no text in a column named Authorization. Please see the code I have below, I thought this may be on the right track but it does not hide any rows.

```
Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
For Each cell In Range("Authorization").End(xlUp)
If cell = "" And cell.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited to add how to define a dynamic named range
It is the fact that you have set the whole column to the name "Authorisation" that I think makes your code freeze, because the whole column is 1 million rows (if you have 2007 or above), and the code will still check even blank rows, so its doing it 1 million times.  1 Option is to rather than set it to the whole column, you could use a "Dynamic Named Range" which will expand and grow as data is added.  There are several different formulas to do this, but based on the fact your data may contain blanks, this version of the formula will expand down to the last populated row in the column.  My example uses colum A as you havent specified what column you are using, so change A to suit your needs.

1. You need to open the Names manager, from the Formulas tab
2. From the dialog box, find your "Authorisation" name.
3. Select it and you should see its current formula at the bottom of the dialog box, replace that with the following formula:
   =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$3,0,0,MATCH("*",Sheet1!$A:$A,-1)-2,1)

In the above formula:

Sheet1 is my sheet, replace it with yours a needed
$A$3 is the starting row of the name, so based on your comments, have set this as column A row 3
0,0, Are defaults you should not need to change
$A$A$ is the column it is counting values, so change as required
-1 is a default, leave as is
-2 is subtracting 2 from the count because we are starting on row 3, so if you change the starting row, change this
the last 1, defined how many columns your named range covers, in your example it is just 1, so this should not need changing.

Once you have defined the name in this way, the code below should work a lot quicker as it will only loop through down to the last row of entered data.  There is one possible issue I can see with this and that is if the very last cell in column A is blank, but the rest of the row isn't, this will miss out the last row. I could fix this by using a different column to count what constitutes the last row, but need to know whicj column would always have a value in it.

< Original answer and code> 
not sure you code matches the description of what you want it to do, namely you seem to be trying to check the row beneath the current cell as well, is this what you really wanted?  Anyhow your syntax is slightly wrong.  I have written and tested this and it works, I have swapped your offset around so my code is checking the cell in the named range "Authorisation" and then also checking the cell to the right.  Amend to suit your needs

```
Sub test()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("Authorisation").Cells
    If c.Value = "" And c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: I agree, my answer was very insufficient. However, When i try the above code, the file always gets frozen. I simply have a column named "Authorization" and I want to hide all the rows in the table that are empty in that column. I want to add this code below lines where I am hiding columns that I do not want when printing.

Comment: When you say it "freezes", just out of interest, you have a whole column named "authorization"?  i.e.  1 million cells?  Can ypu give me some more information about the exact structure of your sheet  i.e.  does it always start at row 1, but is unknown rows?  Both your code and mine will be inefficient if you have named an entire column "authorization", and there are better ways of looping though the rows, but need more info on the structure of your sheet

Comment: There is a header named auhtorization in row 2 and then data down to row 600, list may grow or shrink +/- 200 at any time

Comment: in your code you use "In Range("Authorisation").Cells"  so this means you have a name defined as "Authorisation", so is this hard coded as your 600 rows and has to be changed each time it grows, or is it dynamic, or have you set it to the whole column?

Comment: Column is named, however I realized new columns may be added. The worksheet is a table that starts in row two. Can I use the header "Authorization" so that the bottom of the table can be found and then worked from there? If the cell in "Authorization" is empty, the row should be hidden. I am doing this trying to finish a macro where I am essentitaly setting print paramaters.

Comment: As my response is lengthy, have updated my original answer with how to create a dynamic named range